# How to create date table with given datetime range?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I'm trying to create a table for calendar.But sql server stops at `'2000-01-11 17:45'`. How can i do create dates adding 15 minutes until 2050

```
Create Table Calendar
(id int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary key,CalendarDate DATETIME)


Declare @beginDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
Select @beginDate = '2000-01-01 17:45', @endDate = '2050-01-01 09:00'


While @beginDate <= @endDate 
Begin
    Insert Into dbo.Calendar(CalendarDate)
    Select
        @beginDate As CalendarDate     

    Set @beginDate = DateAdd(MINUTE, 15, @beginDate)
End
```

Comment: Your existing code is very slow, but it works.  This will insert 1,753,214 rows.  Do you have a timeout on the query?  I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I solved the problem thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax suggest `SQL Server`, so i would try with recursive  `CTE` :

```
with cte as (
      select @beginDate as  st
      union all
      select DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, st)
      from cte
      where st < @endDate

)

Insert Into dbo.Calendar(CalendarDate)
   select st as CalendarDate
   from cte
   option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: query stoped at 2000-01-22 03:30:00.000

Comment: sorry it didn't. i selected top 1000